# Javascript error - Iterate over array of itmes

Tags: javascript, neo4j, promise

I have an input in the below format. I need to go over the items and call a query by passing in each value at a time. I tried the below code using "Promise" object but I am not able to retrieve the items individually in the below list.

```
     [ { Codes: [ '123', '234' ] } ]
```

Code I tried:

```
const getByCodes = async ({ neo4j }, { items }) =>
  Promise.all(
    items.map(async ({ Codes }) => {
        return neo4j.run(CodesQuery.getCodesQuery({ items }))
}));
```

New to javascript, so any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: is it possible you're not `await`ing the `Promise.all`?

Comment: @OmegaNalphA: sorry what does that mean?

Comment: `await Promise.all` is what they mean.

Comment: `items.map()` doesn't make a lot of sense here because you're not using the iteration value each time `.map()` calls its callback.  Instead, you're making the exact same call to `neo4j.run(CodesQuery.getCodesQuery({ items }))` every time through the loop iteration.  Why call the same exact thing N times?